# How to detect in JavaScript if a page was loaded in a Chrome webview?

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a packaged app for Chrome that has a webview tag where I load my website.

Is it possible for the website JavaScript code to detect that it was loaded in a webview? The navigator.userAgent property has no clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other approaches in addition to the one mentioned by Jivings:

- Load a slightly different URL in the webview, e.g., http://example.com?in_webview=1, and reflect that in the JavaScript served by the site.
- Same idea but use a #fragment. I don't know for sure whether a #fragment will work correctly, but it if does, it's nice because the server won't get confused by a strange query param.
- Using the embedder, insert a script into the webview's DOM that does something different.

Comment: Right, the first two would definitely work, but it would stop working as soon as I navigated within the webview, as I would lose the extra parameter. Or I would have to keep track of it constantly.

Can you tell me more about the third one? How do I insert a script into the webview's DOM?

Comment: "Or I would have to keep track of it constantly" -- then set a cookie!

Comment: The basic idea for #3 is ExecuteScript("var script = document.createElement('<script>'); script.[make it do whatever you want]; document.body.appendChild(script);"). This gets around the problem that your ExecuteScript otherwise executes in an isolated world, so it can't (for example) change a variable otherwise available in the page.

Comment: Cool, we ended up using the parameter solution, but keeping it in localStorage rather than in a cookie.

Comment: Outstanding! <webview> is under very active development, so please file your bugs at crbug.com or ask here, and we ought to be able to scratch your itch quickly!

Answer (score 0):

When the webview has finished loading fire an event to the page inside:

```
webview.addEventListener("loadstop", function () {
   contentWindow.postMessage('Hello from Chrome App!', targetOrigin)
});
```

Your content page can listen for this message using the regular postMessage API. If it receives a message you will know it is loaded in a webview.

Comment: this is the approach I'm currently using, to set up push messaging, etc. However, this approach is asynchronous and I need to know whether I'm in a webview at page load, not some time later.

Comment: @MarkVayngrib When the page has loaded it will fire that message.

Comment: But if you are in a regular browser it won't fire the message.  When you get the message you know you are in a webview, but if you haven't received it you could be in a regular browser or just checking a bit too soon.  I've been using this approach, but am now worried about timing.