# Call function in a webview from the main page

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm attempting to embed a webview in a packaged app, and in that webview I will display a local page containing results from Google Custom Search, obtained via their javascript API. In order to do that I need to be able to call a function in the webview from the main page of the packaged app.

I could not get the function call from the main page to the webview to work however. I then made a bare bones example, and the function call still would not work. I've included those files below.

I am trying two methods - to inject code, and to pass a message. While I can inject code to set the content of a div, and it works (#1 below), injecting code to call a function does not work (#2), and listening for a message and then calling a function also does not work (#3).

I'm assuming from what I've seen online that this should be possible, so I'm not sure why the function calling cases are not working. If anyone can give me some direction as to why it is not working, I would much appreciate it. Thanks!

### index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="query1" value="test1" /><input type="button" id="submit1" value="Submit #1" />
    <input type="text" id="query2" value="test2" /><input type="button" id="submit2" value="Submit #2" />
    <input type="text" id="query3" value="test3" /><input type="button" id="submit3" value="Submit #3" />

    <webview src="wv.html" id="wv" partition="wv"></webview>
</body>
</html>
```

### wv.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function testCall(mesg) {
            document.getElementById('showtext').textContent = mesg;
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            // Set up message event handler:
            window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
                // call function to display the data
                testCall(event.data);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Webview:</h3>

<div id="showtext"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

### scripts.js

```
function submit1ButtonClicked() {
    document.getElementById('wv').executeScript({ code: "document.getElementById('showtext').textContent = '" + document.getElementById('query1').value + "';" });
}

function submit2ButtonClicked() {
    document.getElementById('wv').executeScript({ code: "testCall('" + document.getElementById('query2').value + "');" });
}

function submit3ButtonClicked() {
    document.getElementById('wv').contentWindow.postMessage(document.getElementById('query3').value, '*');
}

// Initialize the listeners
function initListeners() {
    document.getElementById("submit1").onclick = submit1ButtonClicked;
    document.getElementById("submit2").onclick = submit2ButtonClicked;
    document.getElementById("submit3").onclick = submit3ButtonClicked;

    document.getElementById('wv').addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        document.getElementById('showtext').textContent = event.data;
    });
}

window.onload = initListeners;
```

### main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  // Center window on screen.
  var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
  var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
  var width = 300;
  var height = 300;

  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    id: "TestWebviewID",
    bounds: {
      width: width,
      height: height,
      left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
      top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
    }
  });
});
```

### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TestWebview",
    "version": "1",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "25",
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["main.js"]
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webview"
    ],
    "webview": {
        "partitions": [
            {
                "name": "wv",
                "accessible_resources": ["wv.html"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I added the following to manifest.json then the message passing (method #3) would work:

```
"sandbox": {
  "pages": ["wv.html"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to getting the injected function call method (#2) to work, Fady Samuel on the Chromium Apps discussion list said:

Script injected into a `<webview>` lives in an "isolated world". See here for a description of what isolated worlds are: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment

A work around is to instead inject a script tag. Script within a script tag will run in the same world as the script in the guest content.

Comment: If this information led you to a solution, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work based on the information so far. I posted on the list for some clarification, but no response as of yet.

Comment: This comment would seem to explain the method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253997/how-to-detect-in-javascript-if-a-page-was-loaded-in-a-chrome-webview?rq=1#comment25012005_17256582

Comment: To quote the comment linked to above: ExecuteScript("var script = document.createElement('<script>'); script.[make it do whatever you want]; document.body.appendChild(script);"). This gets around the problem that your ExecuteScript otherwise executes in an isolated world, so it can't (for example) change a variable otherwise available in the page. – sowbug

Comment: So, based on what I've seen online, having it do that with a file would look something like this:

executeScript({ code: "var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src='file.js'; document.body.appendChild(script);" });

However, I'm not sure how one would do it with an arbitrary piece of javascript constructed on the fly, rather than from a file.